# How do I send Bluetooth data from another activity outside of Bluetooth class

Tags: android, function, android-activity, bluetooth

I am having trouble with passing the data (send data) over the bluetooth socket from another Activity outside the Bluetooth Activity. I have multiple classes that I need to execute, a command to send a string through Bluetooth.

Everything works fine from within the Bluetooth class.

Here is my Bluetooth Class

```
public class BTadapter extends Activity implements OnItemClickListener {

    ArrayAdapter<String> listAdapter;
    ListView btlistView;
    BluetoothAdapter btAdapter;
    Set<BluetoothDevice> devicesArray;
    ArrayList<String> pairedDevices;
    ArrayList<BluetoothDevice> devices;
    public static final UUID MY_UUID = UUID.fromString("00001101-0000-1000-8000-00805F9B34FB");
    protected static final int SUCCESS_CONNECT = 0;
    protected static final int MESSAGE_READ = 1;
    IntentFilter filter;
    BroadcastReceiver receiver;
    String tag = "debugging";
    Handler mHandler = new Handler(){

        @Override
        public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
            Log.i(tag, "in handler");
            super.handleMessage(msg);
            switch(msg.what){
                case SUCCESS_CONNECT:
                    // DO something
                    ConnectedThread connectedThread = new ConnectedThread((BluetoothSocket)msg.obj);
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "CONNECTED TO ELD", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();


                    String s = "8";
                    connectedThread.write(s.getBytes());
                    s = System.getProperty("line.separator");
                    connectedThread.write(s.getBytes());
                    Log.i(tag, "Good Connection");


                    ConnectedThread btThread = new ConnectedThread((BluetoothSocket)msg.obj);connectedThread.start();

                    finish();
                    break;
                case MESSAGE_READ:
                    Log.i(tag, "Message Receive POP");
                    byte[] readBuf = (byte[])msg.obj;
                    String string = new String(readBuf);
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), string, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    break;

            }
        }
    };

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.btadapter);
        init();
        if(btAdapter==null){
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "No bluetooth detected", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            finish();
        }
        else{
            if(!btAdapter.isEnabled()){
                turnOnBT();
            }

            getPairedDevices();
            startDiscovery();
        }


    }
    private void startDiscovery() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        btAdapter.cancelDiscovery();
        btAdapter.startDiscovery();

    }
    private void turnOnBT() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Intent intent =new Intent(BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_REQUEST_ENABLE);
        startActivityForResult(intent, 1);
    }
    private void getPairedDevices() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        devicesArray = btAdapter.getBondedDevices();
        if(devicesArray.size()>0){
            for(BluetoothDevice device:devicesArray){
                pairedDevices.add(device.getName());

            }
        }
    }
    private void init() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        btlistView=(ListView)findViewById(R.id.btlistView);
        btlistView.setOnItemClickListener(this);
        listAdapter= new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,0);
        btlistView.setAdapter(listAdapter);
        btAdapter = BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter();
        pairedDevices = new ArrayList<String>();
        filter = new IntentFilter(BluetoothDevice.ACTION_FOUND);
        devices = new ArrayList<BluetoothDevice>();
        receiver = new BroadcastReceiver(){
            @Override
            public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                String action = intent.getAction();

                if(BluetoothDevice.ACTION_FOUND.equals(action)){
                    BluetoothDevice device = intent.getParcelableExtra(BluetoothDevice.EXTRA_DEVICE);
                    devices.add(device);
                    String s = "";
                    for(int a = 0; a < pairedDevices.size(); a++){
                        if(device.getName().equals(pairedDevices.get(a))){
                            //append
                            s = "(Paired)";
                            break;
                        }
                    }

                    listAdapter.add(device.getName()+" "+s+" "+"\n"+device.getAddress());
                }

                else if(BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_DISCOVERY_STARTED.equals(action)){
                    // run some code
                }
                else if(BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_DISCOVERY_FINISHED.equals(action)){
                    // run some code



                }
                else if(BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_STATE_CHANGED.equals(action)){
                    if(btAdapter.getState() == btAdapter.STATE_OFF){
                        turnOnBT();
                    }
                }

            }
        };

        registerReceiver(receiver, filter);
        filter = new IntentFilter(BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_DISCOVERY_STARTED);
        registerReceiver(receiver, filter);
        filter = new IntentFilter(BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_DISCOVERY_FINISHED);
        registerReceiver(receiver, filter);
        filter = new IntentFilter(BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_STATE_CHANGED);
        registerReceiver(receiver, filter);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        if(resultCode == RESULT_CANCELED){
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Bluetooth must be enabled to continue", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            finish();
        }
    }
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2, long arg3) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        if(btAdapter.isDiscovering()){
            btAdapter.cancelDiscovery();
        }
        if(listAdapter.getItem(arg2).contains("Paired")){

            BluetoothDevice selectedDevice = devices.get(arg2);
            ConnectThread connect = new ConnectThread(selectedDevice);
            connect.start();
            Log.i(tag, "in click listener");
        }
        else{
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "device is not paired", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    }
    public class ConnectThread extends Thread {

        private final BluetoothSocket mmSocket;
        private final BluetoothDevice mmDevice;

        public ConnectThread(BluetoothDevice device) {
            BluetoothSocket tmp = null;
            mmDevice = device;
            Log.i(tag, "construct");
            try {
                tmp = device.createRfcommSocketToServiceRecord(MY_UUID);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                Log.i(tag, "get socket failed");

            }
            mmSocket = tmp;
        }

        public void run() {
            btAdapter.cancelDiscovery();
            Log.i(tag, "connect - run");
            try {
                mmSocket.connect();
                Log.i(tag, "connect - succeeded");
            } catch (IOException connectException) {    Log.i(tag, "connect failed");
                try {
                    mmSocket.close();
                } catch (IOException closeException) { }
                return;
            }

            mHandler.obtainMessage(SUCCESS_CONNECT, mmSocket).sendToTarget();
        }

        public void cancel() {
            try {
                mmSocket.close();
            } catch (IOException e) { }
        }
    }
    public class ConnectedThread extends Thread {
        private final BluetoothSocket mmSocket;
        private final InputStream mmInStream;
        private final OutputStream mmOutStream;

        public ConnectedThread(BluetoothSocket socket) {
            mmSocket = socket;
            InputStream tmpIn = null;
            OutputStream tmpOut = null;
            try {
                tmpIn = socket.getInputStream();
                tmpOut = socket.getOutputStream();
            } catch (IOException e) { }

            mmInStream = tmpIn;
            mmOutStream = tmpOut;
        }

        public void run() {
            byte[] buffer;  // buffer store for the stream
            int bytes; // bytes returned from read()

            // Keep listening to the InputStream until an exception occurs
            while (true) {
                try {
                    // Read from the InputStream
                    buffer = new byte[1024];
                    bytes = mmInStream.read(buffer);
                    // Send the obtained bytes to the UI activity
                    mHandler.obtainMessage(MESSAGE_READ, bytes, -1, buffer)
                            .sendToTarget();
                    Log.i(tag, "Message Received");
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    break;
                }
            }
        }

        /* Call this from the main activity to send data to the remote device */
        public void write(byte[] bytes) {
            try {
                mmOutStream.write(bytes);
            } catch (IOException e) { }
        }

        /* Call this from the main activity to shutdown the connection */
        public void cancel() {
            try {
                mmSocket.close();
            } catch (IOException e) { }
        }
    }

    public void BTwrite(String s){
        Log.i(Tag, "Sending over Bluetooth");
        sendThread.write(s.getBytes());
        s = System.getProperty("line.separator");
        sendThread.write(s.getBytes());
        Log.i(Tag, "Bluetooth write sent.");

   }

    public void onBackPressed() {
        finish();
    }
    public void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        finish();
    }
}
```

Here is the call from Main activity

```
BT.BTwrite("2");
```

Here is the error I receive

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void logit.dot.BTadapter$ConnectedThread.write(byte[])' on a null object reference
                                                           at logit.dot.BTadapter.BTwrite(BTadapter.java:382)
                                                           at logit.dot.Main.insert(Main.java:1016)
                                                           at logit.dot.Main.access$4400(Main.java:54)
                                                           at logit.dot.Main$13.onClick(Main.java:1233)
                                                           at com.android.internal.app.AlertController$ButtonHandler.handleMessage(AlertController.java:165)
                                                           at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:111)
                                                           at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:194)
                                                           at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5576)
                                                           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
                                                           at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:955)
                                                           at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:750)
```

Comment: Remove `finish()` from your `onActivityResult` method. Actually, just remove all instances of `finish()` in your code. Also, register/unregister all receivers in the `onResume()` and `onPause()` methods, if the receivers will use an instance of an Activity.

Comment: I did this and it did not resolve the issue. I am receiving a new error message as indicated in the question

Answer (score -1):

Try to make the bluetoothSocket as a static object. So you will init it once time and call it like **MainActivity.bluetoothSocket**. Then  you can work as you like ,it's like you have a shared object between class.

Comment: A static Socket object can cause  a memory leak, though